# Implement Exponential Back off in NiFi using RetryFlowFile processor

Tags: apache-nifi, exponential-backoff

As a part of error handling in NiFi, I am trying to implement retry mechanism on InvokeHTTP Processor. I made use of RetryFlowFile Processor which does the job of retrying for 'x' number of times. My query is, is there any inbuilt Processor which can implement Exponential Back Off logic along with RetryFlowFile Processor to achieve retry mechanism.